# Calculate how early the correct prediction was made

Tags: python, pandas, classification

I have a dataset where each row is a point in time of a customer lifecycle. I ran the logistic regression on the data with the target variable as to whether the customer 'churn' or not. I capture the predictions and add to the dataframe. Below is the sample dataset with the predictions:

[image]

I want to now calculate, for each individual customer, how early in his/her lifetime was the prediction made correctly? And then aggregate on the entire customer set to build a custom metric for the classification model.

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is how i calculated the metric. If someone knows a better solution, please let me know:

```
total_count = 0
true_pred = 0
tenure= validation_data['tenure'].unique()
for i in range(len(tenure)):
    running_tenure = i+1
    for index, row in validation_data.iterrows():    
        if row['tenure'] == running_tenure :
            total_count += 1
            if row['churn'] == row['pred_churn']:
                true_pred += 1
    Accuracy = float(float(true_pred)/total_count)))
```